# How to join tables easily Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, select-into, sql

I have two separate tables used for categories.

One is `Categories(ID, Title, Description)`, and the other is `SubCategories(ID, UpperID, Title, Description)`

I want to insert the records from categories to SubCategories with upperID=0. I've looked at SQL `SELECT INTO` but don't know how to use it for existing tables.

Comment: Do you want to maintain initial IDs of Categories ? and if so, are they not present in the SubCategories ?

Comment: I want to join this tables because I want to be able to set a category or subcategory id for another record (in case its a factory) in database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Insert Into dbo.SubCategories (UpperId, Title, Description)

Select 0, Title, Description
From dbo.Categories
```

This assumes that the ID column in both tables is an Identity column and that the ID in Categories should not be transferred to the SubCategories table

Comment: adding to the answer, if you want to pass the ID as well (*and it is non-conflicting with existing keys*) use the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT SubCategories  ON`

Comment: I was going to add this in but as I'm not 100% sure what the OP wants I decided to leave it out to avoid confusion.  Still a good point to make though.

Comment: Used: INSERT INTO dbo.Categories (UpperId, Title, Description) SELECT UpperID, Title, Description FROM dbo.SubCategories; Because subcategories had ID's from categories so now I don't need to change catID's :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO SubCategories(ID, UpperID, Title, Description)

SELECT ID, 0, Title, Description FROM Categories
```

assuming that Id is not Identity field.

Comment: -, this will give you an error with mssql ...! take a look at barry's answer (which has correct syntax)

Comment: NO... if you are talking about Identity then I have explained about it.

Comment: nope... it's not about identity ... it's just your invalid syntax: `INSERT INTO TABLE (Column1, Column2, ...) VALUES (SubSelect)` is not valid. it must state `INSERT INTO TABLE (Column1, Column2, ...) SubSelect`